# Show rows as columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table `t`

**Table name:** t
**key** :  c1

```
|----+----+----|
| c1 | c2 | c3 |
|----+----+----|
|  1 | A  | $  |
|  2 | B  | *  |
|  3 | C  | ^  |
|----+----+----|
```

I need to select two rows from the table and show them side by side like this:

```
| 1 | 2 |
| A | B |
| $ | * |
```

For smaller tables like this, I could concat each values and show like this:

```
SELECT concat (t1.c1, " | ", t2.c1),
       concat (t1.c2, " | ", t2.c2),
       concat (t1.c3, " | ", t2.c3)
FROM t AS t1,
     t AS t2
WHERE t1.c1 = 1
  AND t2.c1 = 2;
```

Not sure how to go about large tables with many columns since I have to give name of each column explicitly.

Pretty helpful for me if I need to compare two rows and see where they differ. Showing them as rows itself is one way but, my table row won't fit  inside screen width.

Comment: Does the column c1 give some sort of order to the rows?

Comment: yes, c1 is the key. I will update the question.

Comment: Rotate your monitor. Seriously, consider handling issued of data display in application code

Comment: I am not clear what your output would look like if you had a row with c1 = 4.

Comment: @Strawberry, particular select is just for debugging purpose to see where two rows differ.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)